# communication between instances of classes

Tags: php, oop

I have a loop that creates 1-* instances of classes. All classes are a child class of one abstract class, so they all respond the same, though they do different things. 
This loop runs 3 times: create, validate, run. However, I'm running into business logic between the classes. If  is created,  cannot run. If  is created,  must run.
Currently, all these checks are in the loop itself and it's getting messy and making it less flexible than my original idea.

Q: Is there any way to move the business logic INTO the class's validation function?

```
class Parent{
    abstract function validate();
    abstract function run();
}

class A extends Parent{
    function validate(){/*validation*/}
    function run(){/*what A does*/}
}

class B extends Parent{
    function isClassAthere(){}
    function validate(){
       // validation
       if($this->isClassAthere()) return FALSE; // this is the one I want
    }
    function run(){/*what B does*/}
}

class C extends Parent{
    function isClassBthere(){}
    function validate(){
       // validation
       if($this->isClassBthere()) return TRUE;
    }
    function run(){/*what C does*/}
}
```

all called by

```
foreach( $classnames as $index=>$name ){
    $instances[$index] = new $name();
    if(!$instances[$index]->validate()) return FALSE;
    // Business logic is here, I want to move it to validate()
}
foreach( $instances as $instance ){
    $instance->run();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more what your classes look like? Maybe you made an OOP assumption mistake.

Comment: The answers given aren't really satisfying to me. All of the child classes extending `Parent` have a dependency, the question is, should class `B` know if `A` is there and class `C` know if `B` is there. The real obvious to me would be a class that does the validation, e.g. dependency check. The function name `isClassAThere` really says `Class`, does this check for the class `A` to be present? Or the instantiated object of class `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try and save all created instances as static properties of the parent class

```
class B{
  // static properties are accessible
  // though no instance of the class
  // has been created yet
  static public instances = array();

  // php magic function __construct
  // gets called every time an object
  // of this class gets created
  public function __construct(){
    B::instances[] = $this;
  }
  ..
}

class C{
  ...
  public function validate(){
    // as said before, B::instances
    // is available, even if there is no
    // object of class B.
    return ( count(B::instances) > 0 ) ? true : false;
  }
```

Comment: I'll try this one. I like the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should move the validation out of the classes. If you separate the concerns into objects which do work, and objects which *tell* them to do work, then you may have what you want.

```
class A{}

class B{}

class ABValidator{
    public function validate($instances = array())
}

ABValidator::validate(array(
    new A(),
    new B(),
));
```